# Posing on Pose Mode is bugged(2.8). Deforming mesh by every action

Tags: pose-mode

I have a problem while using the pose mode.

To start off, idk if this is a feature of blender 2.8 but...

when im deforming my mesh in pose mode with bendy bones i need to "refresh" (by clicking or presing any key), in order to see the final result.

Idk if i was clear at all. But its something like this.

EG:
In a normal situation
When you're deforming a mesh on pose mode, you just move the bone and voilah! you have already the deformed mesh by moving a bone.

In my case: using bendy bones
When i move the bone i need to spam click or keys to see how it actually looks the deformed mesh.

(I have to clarify that im using copy rotation bone constraints)

Another example with images

Mesh on its original pose mode.
[image]

After moving it.
[image]

After "refreshing"(spamming clicks) too many times to get the real look of the deformed mesh
[image]

Maybe im just too noob and this thing is normal in any version of Blender while using Bendy Bones, idk, but... the thing is that this is annoying AF and it takes me 1 hour to achieve 1 simple pose :(

Comment: Are you aware that this might be a bug in Blender 2.80 **beta** and Blender Stackexchange is not the [Blender Bucktracker](https://developer.blender.org/)?

Comment: Well... Nope, actually its not a bug, hehe. I mean, it can be replicated on early versions of Blender. The thing is that i found that it behaves like that because the bones have copy rotation constraint on .6, .4, and on... so, in a simple way of telling this, when rotating the object behaves like the movement of a worm because the copy rotation constraint on the different bones following the rotation of the next bone, making it look like that and behave like that. Idk how to explain it precisely xd, but no, its not related to 2.8.